# Does posting my computer name publicly make my system vulnerable?

Tags: privacy, attack-prevention

I am wondering if it is paranoia and/or privacy overkill to block out one's computer name when posting terminal output in public forums? I don't know enough about networking to know if it's possible that this information could make one's system vulnerable somehow (though I suspect not?) and was hoping someone could shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, no. Your computer should not be reachable from outside your local network, with the name or without.

However, it can leak info like your real name, or allow people who know your computer name to match your online username to the real you. Whether this is a major concern is up to you.

Comment: How can it not be reachable without on the local network? You can do `\\computername` via network.

Comment: @MarkBuffalo *Outside* the local network. \\computername will not work if you are not on the same local network as that computer - and if it's posted to the internet, the vast vast majority of viewers are not going to be on your local network.

Comment: I should've worded it better. If you're on the same local network, it can be used to access the device if the permissions are appropriate. Then again, you did say, "generally."

Comment: @MarkBuffalo One can pretty easily get a list of all the computers in a local network, so hiding it from them is pretty irrelevant anyway.

Comment: Agreed. It's not too difficult.